# Google Chrome suddenly downgrades

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, 64-bit

**Google Chrome** downgrades itself to *26.0.1410.64*

I uninstall, reinstall and it works great, running the latest version. But as soon as I close and reopen it, the message "*Your profile could not be opened correctly*" appears and it's already downgraded.

Once it does that, if I go to `chrome://chrome/` it says that there was an error during update (**error: 1**).

The account sync only works fine when it is just installed, after this error it's only partially in sync.

I'm now running a full antivirus scan just in case. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Using Windows 7 64bit

**UPDATE**

Full scan with Avast turned out clean.
Spybot Search & Destroy too...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that if you start installing programs on **C:** (The normal way) and later on change the **Program Files** directory (You would normally do this when using an SSD, to avoid filling it)
Google Chrome will update *once* to the new location, but it will keep on running the version on **C:**.

Basically I though it was *downgrading* itself, although it was just running the last version installed before I changed the Program Files directory.

A simple fix is to delete everything related to Chrome, reinstall, and then manually change the desktop and start menu links.